# Feature with Id 'guid' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope

Tags: 2013, feature, site-collection, solution-package, feature-activation

I have a WinForms project that acts as a Sharepoint 2013 Solution installer. It basically do some checking, create a sql database, adds and install a SP Solution and finally activates the feature.

The feature is scoped to "Site Collection" and the code to activate it is the following:

```
SPFeature feature = siteCollection.Features.Add(featureId.Value, true);
```

In some environments this works well. But in others this throws the following exception:

> Feature with Id 'guid' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be
>   added to this scope.

I've searched this exception and found some solutions that doesn't apply to my case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some details about the farm topology? Is this a multi server farm? If so do all servers have the web application role activated? Are you able to activate the features using powershell (Enable-SPFeature) on the same box?

Comment: I'm testing this installer in Cloudshare environments, which are just one VPS with SP2013 and everything needed to run it. Yes, I can manually enable the feature via the site and also via powershell.

Comment: Is your your windows app compiled for windows x64?

Comment: @MarcoScheel Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure the solution deployment job was finished before you activate the feature.

have a look at this blog: [Programmatically waiting on SharePoint Solutions to deploy](http://blog.krichie.com/2011/09/02/programmatically-waiting-on-sharepoint-solutions-to-deploy/)

Comment: The installer is based on this project: http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/ which already has a step that waits for the deployment job to be finished before trying to activate the feature.

Comment: Have a look at the solution deploy status when you get the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure the feature is actually installed on the farm.  You can look in the 15 HIVE for the feature folder.  In addition, you can look at the Get-SPFeature PowerShell Cmdlet output to see if it gets listed.